# Could someone help me debug the gesturedetector for this recipe app in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, debugging

I had some code for a recipe app in flutter, and I decided to create a recipe detail page and incorporate it into the app. I made the page, and added a gestureDetector as well as navigation.push() into both the carousel and popular recipe list but the code appears to be bugged, since the image carousel doesn't show up. The popular recipe list doesn't lead to the detail page either. Here's the repository https://github.com/sldgjrg/Recipe-App-Flutter

Comment: please put the code that you have problem with not  link of a repository.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sry about that. Will do in future!

Answer (score 0):

Few things were missing and need to be optimised as below:

`home_screen.dart` build function needs few modifications as below:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFe7eefb),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: PageViewRecipeList(
                recipes: recipes,
                onRecipeTap: (recipe) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    RecipeDetailArguments.routeName, // use the named route
                    arguments: recipe,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const Expanded(child: PopularRecipeList()),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const MyBottomNavigationBar(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showSearch(context: context, delegate: MySearchDelegate());
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          child: const Icon(Icons.search),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Missing `onGenerateRoute` in main.dart. This is required
to generate the dynamic route to the pages you want to open

```
home: const OnboardingScreen(),
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/recipe_detail') {
      final value = settings.arguments as Recipe; // Retrieve the value.
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => RecipeDetailPage(
              recipe: value)); // Pass it to RecipeDetailPage.
    }
    return null; // Let `onUnknownRoute` handle this behavior.
  },
```

In `popular_recipe_list.dart`, import the class `RecipeDetailArguments` and update the `onTap` function as below:

```
 onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            RecipeDetailArguments.routeName, // use the named route
            arguments: recipes[index],
          );
          // Navigator.pushNamed(
          //   context,
          //   '/recipe-detail',
          //   arguments: recipes[index],
          // );
        },
```